# Merge local and online database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a system.. an inventory system and I want it to have an online and offline mode.I want to have an offline for it so that I can insert, delete and edit data even there's no internet connection.

Moreover, I want to merge the data from local database with the data from the online database when there is an internet connection. How to do it with Php and mysql?

Can anyone help me to solve this? Do you have an idea on how to do this staff?

Comment: Merging a database with another one is a bad practice and its not a solution.. you should go for any other option rather than merging the data

Comment: you need to read about mysql replication, master-slave.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. It seems like you're asking about the high-level design of an application, but there's not enough detail to answer that properly. The language and database you choose really have nothing to do with your design problem. I recommend giving it a try in PHP and asking specific questions with code examples when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can add uuid (guid), datetime and operation (insert,update,delete) column on every table. Systems must save every successful sync date time to anywhere.
You can sync all table rows after last successful sync when has connection. But two different system changing same row is problem in this methodologies. My be you can design system with insert&delete instead using update.